# WIX use Corvid API with 3rd party website

Tags: velo

Is there a way to use the WIX Corvid API for external App, to retrieve the product Data.
I'm not able to find the SDK which we can use.
Our Client Wants to manage it product from a different platform.
we want a way to create/update/get product and order from the WIX store.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not get CORS error:

Change the below origin strings to your own origin.

This should resolve your CORS issue.

```js
import {ok, badRequest, response} from 'wix-http-functions';

function validate(origin) {
    if (origin == "http://localhost:4200" || origin == "http://localhost:4201") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

export function options_yourFunctionName(request) {
    console.log(request);

    let headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400"
    }

    if (validate(request.headers.origin)) {
        headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = request.headers.origin;
    }

    return response({ "status": 204, "headers": headers });
}


export function post_yourFunctionName(request) {
    console.log("post_duxLogin");
    const _response = {
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    };

    if (validate(request.headers.origin)) {
        _response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] =
            request.headers.origin;
        _response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type";
    }

    // Perform other things here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [HTTP Functions](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference//wix-http-functions.html) to expose your sites API. Then you can send POST requests via the external app to your site's endpoint and based on the request parameters or body you can query your product data (provided its in a database collection) and return items to the external service.

As far as create/update/get goes, you can only do that as much as the Wix Stores Backend API allows you to: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-stores-backend.html